# Mapbox navigation Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, mapbox

Quick question,
Is Mapbox Navigation compatible with Ionic? I can only find SDK for both Android & iOs but nothing on cross platform technologies.
https://www.mapbox.com/navigation-sdk/

Comment: I believe you can use web version and it will still work on a real device. I assume you do not need use Sdk for it.

Comment: I'm looking to build both Android & iOs app. What do you mean by using a web version?

Comment: What I meant is you can use https://docs.mapbox.com/api/ and it will work as expected. Look this one for example https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/simple-map/ this code will work on any Ionic project without any issue.

Comment: Yes but this project is only for showing a map, while i'm looking for a more advanced feature (the navigation).

Comment: @OualidFouad did you find a way to integrate the Mapbox integration and its other API features?

Comment: Won't be able to tell you if it's possible, I abandoned the project. @KiranRaiChamling